# Compile error for the Hello pass example of llvm

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I was trying the Hello pass example in the ["Writing an LLVM Pass"](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#basiccode) webpage.  I followed the instructions to compile (with gcc-4.2) the Hello.cpp, but I got the compile errors:

> Hello.cpp:20: error:  expected identifier before string constant
>   Hello.cpp:20: error:  expected ',' or '...' before string constant
>   Hello.cpp:20: error:  expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token

which is the line `INITIALIZE_PASS(Hello, "Hello", "Hello World Pass", false, false);` in the program.  The program is:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"  
#include "llvm/Function.h"  
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {  

 struct Hello : public FunctionPass {  
    static char ID;  
    Hello() : FunctionPass(&ID) {}  

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {  
        errs() << "Hello: " << F.getName() << "\n";  
        return false;  
    }  
 };  

 char Hello::ID = 0;  
 INITIALIZE_PASS(Hello, "Hello", "Hello World Pass", false, false);  
}
```

Could any one help me with this?  Thank you very much!

Best,
Daniel

Comment: I am encouraged, there is great need for more working examples : [code examples for learning LLVM backend programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776903/code-examples-for-learning-llvm-backend-programming)

Answer (score 0):

This is the demo code. This should work fine except for line 11, which should be:

```
    Hello() : FunctionPass(ID) {}
```

I am using llvm v2.8, and with that small change everything seems to be working well. But I renamed the program to something else as the Hello pass was already existing.

Follow the instructions in [llvm v2.8, Writing an llvm pass](http://llvm.org/releases/2.8/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#basiccode)

Comment: Indeed, FunctionPass's constructor [takes](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1FunctionPass.html) a `char&` not a `char*`. Looks like the OP is confused by ref/pointer syntax. It would help if he were used to [left-aligning his ampersands](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/).